# Handlebars escaping '\' character and number followed after it in AJAX request even after using {{{ expression

Tags: html, ajax, handlebars.js

I am using an AJAX request and Handlebars to communicate the data transfer as shown below.

**main.hbs**

```
<script>
..

 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    propId: "{{staysAt}}",
                    propImg: "/{{propImg}}",
                    _csrf: "{{csrfToken}}"
                }),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                dataType: 'json',
                url: "/user/sendRequest",
                success: function(result){

                },
                error: function(err){
                    //console.log(err);
                }
            })
..
</script>
```

In `propImg` data is being stored as

```
/uploads 8-11-27T10-54-19.118Zparis-graph-colored.png
```

Instead of

```
/uploads\2018-11-27T10-54-19.118Zparis-graph-colored.png
```

When i use `main.hbs` to display the Handlebar object outside the AJAX request it works perfectly

```
<h2>/{{propImg}}</h2>
```

and gives the complete image path, however inside the AJAX call I do not understand what is going wrong.

I tried using `{{{propImg}}}` for no escape as well however the same issue is coming.

Comment: A `\\` in a JavaScript string literal is an escape character so you will have to escape it itself, with itself. I don't know how to do that in handlebars so...

Comment: @Musa I tried using {{{ expression which is for no escape in Handlebars, yet the same issue is arising

Comment: One option is to put your data in an html data attribute and then read it from there in JS